# How to migrate multiple SVN trunk paths into single Git master without losing history

Tags: git, svn-repository, git-repo

I am having SVN folder structure as shown below:

[image]

and I would like to migrate all different svn trunk paths into single git master.

output:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do it? I am pretty much new to SVN to git migration.
much appreciate for your help.

I have tried svn git clone -s but it is working for only single svn path migration. but I need to migrate multiple svn trunk paths into single git master.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to convert 3 times: convert every SVN repo to a separate git repo, then [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425892/7976758) 3 git repositories into one using either `git subtree` or `git fetch`+`git merge`.